# how to change my current LSTM model from uni to bi-directional?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have built an LSTM model through nn.module. This code is a toy code that I'm using to do stock prediction. I'm trying to make it bidirectional by simply changing the input from `bidirectional = False` to `bidirectional = True` . Although the model runs fine, the problem happens at the for loop of the epoch part where I tried to evaluate the test_loss from nn.MSEloss.

the error code is

`RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1534) must match the size of tensor b (767) at non-singleton dimension 0`

### my model:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, i_size, h_size, n_layers, o_size, dropout=0.1, bidirectional = True):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.num_directions = bidirectional+1
    self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
        input_size=i_size,
        hidden_size=h_size,
        num_layers = n_layers,
        dropout = dropout,
        bidirectional = bidirectional
    )
    self.out = nn.Linear(h_size, o_size)

  def forward(self, x, h_state):
    r_out, hidden_state = self.rnn(x, h_state)

    hidden_size=  hidden_state[-1].size(-1)
    r_out = r_out.view(-1, self.num_directions, hidden_size)
    outs = self.out(r_out)

    return outs, hidden_state
```

### my input:

```
input_size = 100
hidden_size = 64
num_layers = 3
output_size = 1
batch_size = 128

learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 500

rnn = RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, bidirectional =True)
rnn.cuda()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

hidden_state = None
```

### my evaluation process:

```
history = []
x_test_cuda = torch.tensor(x_test).float().cuda()
y_test_cuda = torch.tensor(y_test).float().cuda()

inputs_cuda = torch.tensor(x_train).float().cuda()
labels_cuda = torch.tensor(y_train).float().cuda()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  rnn.train()
  output, _ = rnn(inputs_cuda, hidden_state)
  print(output.size())

  loss = criterion(output[:,0,:].view(-1), labels_cuda)
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
  
  if epoch % 20 == 0:
    rnn.eval()
    test_output, _ = rnn(x_test_cuda, hidden_state)
    test_loss = criterion(test_output.view(-1), y_test_cuda)
    print('epoch {}, loss {}, eval loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item(), test_loss.item()))
  else:
    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
  
  history.append(loss.item())
```

I realized it  is not just a simple change from a True to a False type of question. I have tried to floor division in

`hidden_size=h_size,` or get rid of IF-ELSE part. but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: what did you mean by full traceback?

Comment: It's the full error text that gets printed on the screen containing not only the `RuntimeError` in the last line but also the call stack. It should start with the heading `Traceback`.